# Power BI Report: How to pass Dynamic Values to Parameters in Report Made with Stored Procedure

Tags: report, powerbi, powerbi-embedded, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

```
let
    Source = Sql.Database(MyServer, MyDatabase, [Query="EXEC  [dbo].[spEmployeesRead] '" & ActionCode & "', '" & UserID & "', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '" & Alphabet & "'"])
in
    Source
```

Above is my Stored Procedure in Query Editor its running fine and getting data as i am passing all parameters dynamically including Server Name and Databasename. My Question is I have Saved and Publish the Report to Power BI Service and then Open the Report and from File Menu get Embed Code and pass parameters to this Report URL so i can access this from other Applications and that Application will pass the parameter values dynamically but seems like things are not working correctly. Can anybody check where i am wrong.

```
https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=341f891b-93f8-490a-9a91-62f12f783e2c&groupId=4791121d-01f2-49ad-99fc-9fa3bab7fc3f&autoAuth=true&filter=MyServer eq 'MSSQLSERVER2017' and MyDatabase eq 'TestDB' and EmployeesList/ActionCode eq '1' and EmployeesList/UserID eq '1' and EmployeesList/Alphabet eq 'All'
```

[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JwPzL.png)
[Attached Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6B0sJ.png)

Comment: [ https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=341f891b-93f8-490a-9a91-62f12f783e2c&groupId=4791121d-01f2-49ad-99fc-9fa3bab7fc3f&autoAuth=true&filter=MyServer eq 'MSSQLSERVER2017' and MyDatabase eq 'TestDB' and EmployeesList/ActionCode eq '1' and EmployeesList/UserID eq '1' and EmployeesList/Alphabet eq 'All' ]

**The Above URL Shows Data to me but its not filtering the Records as i change my Parameter values......
i.e. ActionCode = 1  or  ActionCode = 2
Alphabet = "All"    or  Alphbet = "B" **

Comment: With URL query string parameters you can filter the report, but they will not change report parameter values, i.e. it will not re-execute the stored procedure with the values passed in the URL.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct url query available for this condition.

You need to add Parameters and then bind your parameters with custom functions after that you can create url like:

ReportURL?filter=tableName/columnName eq 'value'.

You can check bellow video url for creating parameters and custom function:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iiNDq2VrZPY